# translating filename wildcards to regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to translate arbitrary good old DOS wildcard strings to regex strings, which then are to be used with `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`. Unfortunately, my regex knowledge is quite embarrassing.

I'm trying to wrap my head around stuff like `*.*`, `.*`, and `*.`. My current problem is that `*.` is generally expected to match files that either end with a dot or have no dot at all.
So I translate `*.` into `^.+[^\.].*$`, but this is apparently wrong. It not only matches `blah` and `blah.`, but also `blah.blah`.

So what's the correct regex syntax to match `blah` and `blah.`, but not `blah.blah`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following will work for you

```
^[^.]+\.{0,1}$
```

from start of string match any character but . and the string may end with 0 or 1 .'s

Comment: (Oh, and it turns out I cannot create a file named `blah.`, trying so will create a file `blah`.)

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to create a file whose name *ends* with a dot, but I have observed that the glob `*.` will match a name that **starts** with a dot, if the name has no other dots in it.  For example, it matches `.cvspass`, but not `.antelope.cfg`.  It also matches names with no dots at all.  The regex for that would be `^\.?[^.]+$`.

The "ends with" equivalent would be `^[^.]+\.?$`, but I don't think you need that.  If you also need to match at start **or** end (but nowhere else), you can use `^\.?[^.]+\.?$`.  If the two conditions are mutually exclusive, use `^(?:\.?[^.]+|[^.]+\.)$`