# How can I replicate FileSystemWatcher Filter functionality with Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex, filesystemwatcher

I have a single FileSystemWatcher object for a c# project, and multiple patterns to match when events occur.

As a project requirement, I can't create multiple FileSystemObjects and use individual filter methods to match my patterns. So have to have one filter set to `*.*` to
monitor all files, and when events are created I have to apply a Regex to process matching files per pattern in a loop. My patterns will contain `*` characters, same as how we pass it to Filter method.

How can I replicate the built in filter functionality with single Regex statement?

Some of the many FileSystemWatcher filter scenarios;

- `pi*.txt` (These should match: piano.txt, pie.txt)
- `*.doc` (Anything with the .**doc** extension should match)
- `04*2013.txt` (any text file and it should be any day in the month of april)
- `pi*ar*.jpg` (prefix is **pi**, contains **ar** after prefix anywhere in the file name and has to be a **jpg** extension)
- `pre*ar*pre` (any file with **pre** prefix, followed by **ar** and followed by another **pre**)
- `*.*` (Anything is accepted)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124951/translating-filename-wildcards-to-regex

Comment: Which part do you have problems with? [RegEx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) Syntax can be found [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html), the Regular expression class in .NET is called [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) and uses the normal [expression patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few time back I wrote something similar for my work

```
public static string WildcardPatternToRegexPattern(string pattern)
{
    return string.Format("^{0}$", Regex.Escape(pattern.Replace('/', Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)).Replace(@"\*", ".*").Replace(@"\?", "."));
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it, with some extras too :)

Comment: @Alex - glad i could be of help! do mark question as solved if it solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to learn regex statements, you can start by looking at http://txt2re.com/. if you paste in a piece of text, there is a point and click interface to generate regex expressions for you. i would also recommend just googling "preg".